# If something is considered to be true

Tags: sentence-meaning

If something is considered to be true, but something is not true, is sentence 'something is considered *to be true*' not true?

Comment: This looks more like a philosophy question!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, is 'something is considered to be true' wrong because of phrase 'to be true'?

Comment: There isn't really a question of English here, but a matter of logic.  I think the answer would be the same if you asked the same question in French

Comment: This is indeed a Philosophical question.

Comment: Perhaps if you can give a concrete example.  Don't use "something" but make it more real.

Comment: Are you asking whether 'to be true' is grammatically correct?

Comment: I ask whether 'to be true' is a fact or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase *is considered to be* reports what the speaker believes to be a general opinion. It does not necessarily mean the speaker agrees.

> Christmas is considered to be the happiest time of the year but I think it is the summer solstice.

would be a possible way of showing how it might be used. Of course the speaker may agree as well, it does not necessarily imply they do not.

Comment: I got it. I think I thought only in my respect.